# clojure lazy function - Clojure Koan

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

"Iteration provides an infinite lazy sequence"

```
 (= (range 20) (take 20 (iterate inc 0)))
```

So my question is why it start from 0 instead of 1 ? How to understand the laziness here ?

Comment: `(iterate inc 0)` is an infinite sequence, but it is lazy in the sense that it will not generate more elements, than you asked for (20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[clojure.core/iterate](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/iterate) takes two arguments:

1. the `fn` to apply to the last element in the sequence. When applied, it should produce the next element in the sequence
2. the initial value of the sequence

`(iterate inc 0)` has `0` as the initial element of the sequence.

```
(take 1 (iterate inc 0)) ;; (0)
```

Comment: Yes, but still find strange to use it. Is there any thing I need to know about laziness ? e.g. Consequence of misuse.

Comment: In your example, if you `(take 3 ...)`, `inc` will be executed 2 times. The first element is provided by you, `0`, and `inc` is executed the remaining 2 times; each time the previous element as it's argument.

Answer (score 3):

The koan asks for the iteration to begin at zero because `range` starts at 0 by default, and that makes for nice looking statement. It is typical and useful in programming to start counting at 0 rather than 1. But, The koan could have been written to start at 1 (or any other number for that matter)

```
(= (range 1 21) (take 20 (iterate inc 1)))
```

Here's how iterate is defined

```
user=> (source iterate)
(defn iterate
  "Returns a lazy sequence of x, (f x), (f (f x)) etc. f must be free of side-effects"
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [f x] (cons x (lazy-seq (iterate f (f x)))))
```

So, here's how `(iterate inc 0)` looks at first

```
(cons 0, (lazy-seq (iterate inc (inc 0))))
```

Now when the special lazy-seq element at position 1 (that is, the second position since we count from 0) is first accessed, it is in effect replaced by its expansion.

```
 -- (iterate inc (inc 0)) 
 -> (iterate inc 1) 
 -> (cons 1, (lazy-seq (iterate inc (inc 1))))
```

So, the sequence now looks like

```
-- (cons 0, (lazy-seq (iterate inc (inc 0))))
-> (cons 0, (cons 1 (lazy-seq (iterate inc (inc 1)))))
```

When the special lazy-seq element at position 2 is first accessed, it is in effect replaced by its expansion.

```
 -- (iterate inc (inc 1)) 
 -> (iterate inc 2) 
 -> (cons 2, (lazy-seq (iterate inc (inc 2))))
```

So, the sequence now looks like

```
 -- (cons 0, (cons 1 (lazy-seq (iterate inc (inc 1)))))
 -> (cons 0, (cons 1, (cons 2, (lazy-seq (iterate inc (inc 2))))))
```

Some consequences to be aware, but not typically anything to worry about as a new user

- Any side effects in the body are not executed until accessed, and then only once
- Because you can return a lazy sequence that is not fully realized, beware dependance on dynamic scope, e.g. returning within a `with-` block.
- If you hold a reference to a long/infinite lazy sequence, e.g. `(def numbers (iterate inc 0))` and realize a bunch of them, they will remain in memory. Avoid "holding the head" if this is to be a problem.